# startActivity(i); shows error

Tags: java, android

It shows an error in `"startActivity(i);"`.

> Error: startActivity (android.content.Intent) in Activity cannot be
>   applied.

Here's code:

```
public class LoadingScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SplashInterval = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                this.finish();
            }
            private void finish(){
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        },SplashInterval);
    };
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask the question though :p

Comment: paste LoadingScreen.this.finish(); instead of this.finish();

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class LoadingScreen extends Activity {

    private static int SplashInterval = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }

        },SplashInterval);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
this.finish();
```

which is written inside handler

rather do `LoadingScreen.this.finish();`
to achieve closing of this activity;